# Javascript to C++: Object Equivalent?

Tags: javascript, c++

I've been tasked with converting some code from javascript to C++.  While I'm decently familiar with Javascript, I'm pretty inexperienced with C++.

The javascript code heavily makes use of objects. For example the following code is used to convert angles from degrees to any other specified unit:

```
var allConversions = {
"Angle": {
    "degrees": {
        "degrees":function(inputNum) { return inputNum*1},
        "minutes":function(inputNum) { return inputNum*60},
        "radians":function(inputNum) { return inputNum*0.0174532925},
        "revolutions":function(inputNum) { return inputNum*0.00277777778},
        "seconds":function(inputNum) { return inputNum*3600},
    }
}

exports.convertUnits= function(unitType, inUnit, outUnit, inputVal) {
    return allConversions[unitType][inUnit][outUnit] (inputVal);
}
```

I'm wondering what is the best practice for how to create something similar in C++?  Should I try and create something similar with a struct or class?

Comment: Just create a function and pass the unit types as parameters than do a switch inside that function. No need to have 6 different function that do the same thing. Or just have an array of constants instead of using the switch, there are too many ways to solve this problem.

Comment: Personally I would not try to copy `javascript`. Ignore `javascript`and look at the specifications then craft something in `C++` that fulfills them.

Comment: @Galik: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends a lot on overall structure and context - that is missing in your code snippet. Probably, a simple class with some inline functions would do. But if I had to attempt an equivalent code as provided, I'd have to write something like this:

**someClass.hpp**

```
#ifndef SOMECLASS_H
#define SOMECLASS_H

#include <string>

using std::string;

class degrees
{
    public:
        double inputVal;

        degrees(string, string, string, double); // a constructor

        double degreesFunc(double); // double?, can't have same name func
        double minutes(double);
        double radians(double);
        double revolutions(double);
        double seconds(double);
};

class Angle : public degrees
{
    public:
        Angle(string, string, string, double);
};

class allConversions : public Angle
{
    public:
        allConversions(string, string, string, double);
};

#endif /* SOMECLASS_H */
```

**someClass.cxx**

```
#include "someClass.hpp"

degrees::degrees(
        string unitType,
        string inUnit,
        string outUnit,
        double inputVal)
{
    this->inputVal = inputVal;
}

double degrees::degreesFunc(double inputNum)
{
    return inputNum*1;
}

double degrees::minutes(double inputNum)
{
    return inputNum*60;
}

double degrees::radians(double inputNum)
{
    return inputNum*0.0174532925;
}

double degrees::revolutions(double inputNum)
{
    return inputNum*0.00277777778;
}

double degrees::seconds(double inputNum)
{
    return inputNum*3600;
}

//-------------------------------------------------

Angle::Angle(
        string a,
        string b,
        string c,
        double d)
    : degrees(a, b, c, d) { }

allConversions::allConversions(
        string a,
        string b,
        string c,
        double d)
    : Angle(a, b, c, d) { }
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "someClass.hpp"

using std::cout;

int main()
{
    allConversions convertUnits("what?", "what?", "what?", 10);

    cout << convertUnits.inputVal << '\n';
    cout << convertUnits.radians(10) << '\n';
    cout << convertUnits.minutes(10) << '\n';
}
```

**Compiling with g++ with Makefile:**

```
all:
    g++ -c someClass.cxx
    g++ -c test.cpp
    g++ someClass.o test.o -o run
```

**Run:** `./run`

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly sure what all the down votes are about. I see nothing wrong with your question.

JavaScript is a typeless language, and it's a bit... flexible in it's construction of objects. Depending on the actual code, you have two options and you'll want to use a mix of both.

**Option 1: Create a Class**

In this case, you'd create a class for the specific data structure, with properties for each value you need.

Use this when the JavaScript object is consistent throughout all it's uses.

**Option 2: Use a Hash Map**

There are a variety of different hash map classes. Which you choose is up to the specific version and framework(s) you're using.

Regardless though, these generally work like a JavaScript object, where you can create key/value pairs. Use this when your not quite sure what you're data will be.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Just to ask for a little more clarification, I at times have objects nested inside objects (I can give an example if needed).  Would a hashmap or inheritance in classes be better suited to handle this?

Comment: Again, it'll depend on the exact context. It might be that a class with a hashmap property would be better, or nested hashmaps, or two separate classes. It'll really come down to how well defined the objects are. You should generally prefer classes over hashmaps when it's defined enough.